# Переопределение метода родительского класса

Tags: php, ооп, solid

Мне необходимо наследовать класс и переопределить один родительский метод.
Проблема в том, что у родительского метода, среди параметров вызова, есть 1 параметр, который не нужен в методе наследуемом классе.

Вопрос:

Как можно решить проблему, когда требуется переопределить метод, но с разным кол-вом параметров ? В C++ это делается просто.. без проблем.

Если создать новый метод, то получается, что в наследуемом классе будет болтаться ненужный метод от родителя, который нарушает принципы SOLID.

И второй вопрос, можно ли хотя бы значения по умолчанию изменять в методе наследуемого класса ?

Comment: Переопределите метод как приватный или защищенный, и вызывайте его из нового.

Comment: Что такое переопределение метода но с меньшим количеством параметров? Какой в этом смысл? Налицо ошибка проектирования.

Comment: добавьте к вопросу листинг класса родителя и наследника.